# How to prevent human spammers from sending private messages using PHP

Tags: php, detection, spam

I have a fairly secure authentication and registration system that prevents a lot of bots from secure pages. The problem i have is that the spammers are real humans who keep sending the same message to other users. These message are usually seductive messages with email addresses within them. They can spend hours sending messages then leave.

im using php, im wondering what the best method would be to stop them early. should i detect for email addresses, what approaches would you have to solve this problem.

Comment: What I do, and it works very effectively, is to automatically place people on probation if they trigger a spam trap. For example, if a new account sends a private message (or two or three, pick what works) with a link on one of its first X log-ins, just "ban" the account and forward the suspected spam to yourself. In the off-chance it is legitimate, you can undo the probation.

Comment: What about the case where the spammer simply re-registers with a different email?